# How to filter nested data in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure of data in the firebase database.

```
tripPackages
  -LCoHHZWL-NTLmJKDILV
    50180557210016753
      creationDate:
      farmerID:
      id:
      itemState:
      noOfItems:
      noOfSoldItems:
      totalAmount:
      tripId:
      tvoID:
      vegetableName:
      vid
      weight:
```

Node `trippackages` contains trips which contain packages, where `-LCoHHZWL-NTLmJKDILV` is a trip id, and `50180557210016753` is a package id. Now, I want to filter all the trippackages with a particular `itemState` (say `IN_TRASIT`).

I believe this code should do this:

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("tripPackages").orderByChild("itemState").equalTo("IN_TRANSIT");
```

where value of child `itemState` is an enum in my POJO, but I am not able to achieve the desired results.

*Does the nested location level of child or type of the value of child in POJO has anything to do with it?*

I am able to successfully filter data in similar data structure when the nested location level of child on which `orderByChild` used is 2 and value of child is a `String`.

Comment: 0 children even when there are multiple children with `itemState:"IN_TRANSIT"`

Answer (score 1):

> Does the nested location level of child or type of the value of child in POJO has anything to do with it?

Yes, it affects. You have this database:

```
tripPackages  
   -LCoHHZWL-NTLmJKDILV
           50180557210016753
                   itemState: IN_TRANSIT
```

To be able to filter according to the value of `itemState`, try the following:

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("tripPackages").child("-LCoHHZWL-NTLmJKDILV").orderByChild("itemState").equalTo("IN_TRANSIT");
```

You need to add the trip id, to be able to filter the data according to the `itemState`

Comment: I can not do that as I do not know the pushIDs (`.child("pushID")`) where I fetch the data. I just want all the packages with `itemState:"IN_TRANSIT"` under the node `tripPackages`, and I do not have IDs for all the trips (immediate child of the node `tripPackages`).

Comment: Can you please direct me to the docs that talk about the limitations of `orderByChild` or `equalTo` in relation to the nested location level of the data.

Comment: Can you access this `50180557210016753`?

Comment: if you can try this then, `firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("tripPackages").orderByChild("50180557210016753/itemState").equalTo("IN_TRANSIT");`

Comment: This is the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data (not sure if it talks about the limitation that much). But when you use `orderByChild` you can skip one node, as I did in the answer and in the comment above this one.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have the access to the package Id as well.

Comment: Docs do not discuss anything about such limitations. I have spent considerable amount of time on it, and I have read docs thoroughly, I think :P.

Comment: yes but I'm telling you, I'm the docs :p. If you cannot access both ids then how are you gonna access the `itemState`?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database can only query children one level under a specific location. So you can query the packages of an individual trip (by querying on `/tripPackages/-LCoHHZWL-NTLmJKDILV`), but not across all trips.

Typical solutions are to store the packages as a list and give them a trip ID property, or to store an additional list of "package IDs by state".

Also see my answers here, which both contain a good example of the data structure to solve this:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).